# HttpContext.Current cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have a line

```
string serializedContext = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(HttpContext.Current)
```

but I am getting exception on this line.

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Context' with type 'System.Web.HttpContext'. Path 'ApplicationInstance'.

I am trying to pass serailized context to web service.
Why that self-referencing loop is detected and what could be the way out?

Comment: You simply can't do that... And more importantly you will not be able to hydrate it on other end into working state... Sending only data that is necessary is the solution.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to serialize the current HttpContext?

Comment: This might be an X-Y problem. what is the end goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @BrianRogers I want to serialize session to send it to the web service. The reason is, when I call a method from service that has Session in it, I get `HttpContext.Current` as `null`, so I was trying to pass context to web service and forward that to a method that uses session and deserialize it there to get actual session, not null.

Comment: May be you should post the entire code to understand the real issue. What you are trying to do right now is definitely so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**The Misconception:**

Serializing your context and de-serialize it on the other side makes no semantical sense: if you send it to a remote web service, it will have its own http context.

**Working around the problem**
Instead, what you might want to do is : create a new object with just the data you need to use on the remote web service.

Don't consider it as being a context, think of it as a data transfer object that contains all the things you need to get the job done on the other side.

**Additional considerations**

You might think it is painful to basically create a new object that contains the same data as your HttpContext, but you can mitigate the tediousness of copying the values from one object to the other by using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) in order to copy the values from one object to the other without the need to write the code yourself (it is convention-based).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

You can try :

```
string serializedContext = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(HttpContext.Current, Formatting.Indented, 
new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```